# Why do debug logs not always work for a @future method?

Tags: apex, future, debugging

I'm working on an Apex class that contains a method annotated with `@future`. Inside of the method I have a few `system.debug` statements I'm using to figure out why it's not working. The problem is -- if I run my code via the Developer Console and inspect the execution log, it only shows up about half the time. Why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem was -- I was executing anonymous code and checking the "Open Log" option. The call was actually generating two separate logs -- one for the anonymous code, and another for `FutureHandler`, and one or the other would open randomly. This is what made it seem like it was only working some of the time. So instead, I clicked on the Logs tab in the lower pane of the Developer Console and there they both were. Just make sure you click on the `FutureHandler` one :)